# "a" element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to have a function that puts the code inside it in an HTML "a" element. I have tried many different variations of the code posted below and none of them have worked.

```
    var doc = document.body;

    function h1(text) {
        var h1 = document.createElement("h1");
        var t = document.createTextNode(text);
        h1.appendChild(t);
        doc.appendChild(h1);
    }

    function a(a, b) {
        var doc1 = document.createElement("a");
        doc.a;
        var s;
        s = document.createElement('script');
        s.innerHTML = b;
        doc.appendChild(doc1);
        doc = doc1;
        doc1.appendChild(s);
        doc = document.body;
    }

    a("href=www.google.com", "h1(\"hello\");");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/huzuno93/

Comment: so what exactly is going on here, for instance `doc.a` looks like it would equal something like `document.body."href=www.google.com"` and I don't see how that would be valid anything?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/huzuno93/1/

Comment: I think that the `s = ...` and the line below it could be replaced with `s = eval(b);`. That said, the fact that that's true suggests you really should be designing this a different way.

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do? Why are you putting a `<script>` element inside an `<a>`?

Comment: WTH is going on there? What are these lines `doc.a;`, `doc = doc1;` and `doc = document.body;` supposed to do? They can and should simply be omitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm curious how you arrived at that particular attempt, but here is how you could do this correctly (at least this is what I think you're trying to do):

```js
var doc = document.body;

function h1(text) {
  var h1 = document.createElement("h1");
  var t = document.createTextNode(text);
  h1.appendChild(t);
  return h1;
}

function a(a, b) {
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  link.href = a;

  link.appendChild(b);
  return link;
}

doc.appendChild(a("http://www.google.com", h1("hello")));
doc.appendChild(h1("wazzap"));
```

In general, I would recommend against having functions whose parameters or variables have the same name as themselves. That makes it very confusing.

Comment: Yes, that does work. However, than I cannot do this `h1("hello");`

Comment: Can you help me out by giving me code where I could do both?

Comment: @crank123 The problem is that you are conflating the process of creating an element with the process of attaching it to the DOM. You should create your elements, and then attach them to the DOM (see my edited answer above).

Comment: Is there any way of doing this without having to put doc.appendChild first?

Comment: @crank123 Sure, it's possible, but clean, reusable code is preferable than hard-to-follow minimalist code, so I suggest using the above approach.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @JLRishe your answer really helped me figure this one out. After, reviewing you code, editing mine, and digging through the internet for solutions I can up with this.

```
    function h1(text) {
        base = document.createElement("h1");
        var t = document.createTextNode(text);
        base.appendChild(t);
        doc.appendChild(base);
    }
    function a() {
        doc1 = document.createElement("a");
        doc.appendChild(doc1);
        doc1.appendChild(base);
    }
    function href(a) {
        doc1.href = a;
    }

    a(h1("hello"));
    href("www.google.com");
    h1("hello");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7ju91jpm/

It doesn't work for me in JSFiddle, but it works where I need it to.